# How to insert a hyperlink without escaping the URL?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document that looks something like this:

[image]

I'm writing a program that takes these `{{input}}`'s, replaces them in the Word document, and saves.

My problem is, I want to insert a link to `mailto:{{email}}`, but Word changes that to `mailto:%7b%7bemail%7d%7d`.

How can I insert the link with the raw URL, unescaped?

I tried using a link instead of an email address. Same problem.

I tried using `\{` instead of `{` - same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try showing field codes (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) and inserting the desired text into the field code manually.

Comment: This works perfectly man; you're a genius!! Although when the link is hovered over, it still shows the escaped version in the status bar; it *does* work. The fields are replaced perfectly! Thanks again.